# i am Struggling with Regex , Pattern matcher always return false

Tags: regex, salesforce, apex, salesforce-lightning, salesforce-service-cloud

Case record has Description field which will hold value like

```
[https://s3.amazonaws.com/deep-email-resources/logo-big.png]

 

Detection Event - Europe - UK - Nordics - UK-HSE Bootle  *[151]

 

Event ID
```

Now i want a REGEX which should match `[151]` from Description Field. i have written below code but this always returns false .

```
Case ca=[Select Id,Description,Subject from Case Where Id='500DP00000HSWwnYAH'];
Boolean TestMatch = Pattern.matches('(\\\\*\\[\\d+\\])', ca.Description);
system.debug('TEST Regex '+TestMatch);
```

i have tried with diffrent Regex , but i think i am missing to match `newLine WhiteSpace`

Comment: I don't think you need all those backslashes before `*`. Try `'(\\*\\[\\d+\\])'`

Comment: You should try to print out the string after it's parsed. From what I know:  raw: `(\*\[\d+\])` Php: `'(\*\[\d+\])'` JS: `'(\\*\\[\\d+\\])'`

Answer (score 0):

you can try this pattern : [[0-9]*], if numbers like 151 is surrounded by square brackets only.